# Pascal. Ввод информации в массив и вывод через процедуры

Tags: массивы, строки, pascal, процедуры

Пользователю выводится меню: 
1. Добавить авто
2. Список авто
0. Выход

1)При выборе «Добавить авто», пользователю выпадают следующие параметры, которые он по-очереди должен вводить: марка, модель, цвет, цена, опции (3 штуки).

2)При выборе «Список авто», программа выводит все введённые поля на экран.

Пытался реализовать задачу через процедуры и массив, но компилятор всё равно не выводит программу: пишет ошибку, когда доходит до поля "Введите номер".

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где могут быть ошибки.

```
Type

tAuto=record
Mark: string[20];
Model: string[20];
Colour: string[20];
Price: integer;
Options: Array[1..3] of tOption;
end;

tOption=record
ID: integer;
Name: string[40];
end;

tCars= array of tAuto;

Procedure AddAutos(Cars: tCars); // добавить авто
Var
i,j: integer;
auto: tAuto;
Begin
begin

Writeln('Введите марку: ');
readln(auto.Mark);
Writeln('Введите модель: ');
readln(auto.Model);
Writeln('Введите цвет: ');
readln(auto.Colour);
Writeln('Введите цену: ');
readln(auto.Price);
for j := 1 to 3 do begin
Writeln('Введите номер: ');
readln(auto.Options[i].ID);
Writeln('Введите название опции: ');
readln(auto.Options[i].Name);

Setlength(Cars, length(cars)+1);
Cars[length(cars)-1] := auto;
end;
end;
End;

Procedure TypeAutos(cars: tCars); //вывод списка
Var
i,j: integer;
Begin
for i := 1 to length(cars) do
begin
Writeln('Марка: ',Cars[i].Mark);
Writeln('Модель: ',Cars[i].Model);
Writeln('Цвет: ',Cars[i].Colour);
Writeln('Цена: ',Cars[i].Price);
for j := 1 to 3 do begin
Writeln('Номер: ',Cars[i].Options[i].ID);
Writeln('Название опции: ',Cars[i].Options[i].Name);
end;
end;
End;

Var
Cars: tCars;
f: TextFile;
x, i: integer;

Begin // меню
Repeat
Writeln('Что вы хотите сделать?');
Writeln('1 - Добавить авто');
Writeln('2 - Список авто');
Writeln('0 - Выход');
Readln(x);
if x=1 then
AddAutos(Cars);
if x=2 then
TypeAutos(Cars);
Until x=0;

End.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас `tAuto`  определен раньше, чем `tOption`, поменяйте их местами.

Далее, в цикле

```
for j := 1 to 3 do begin
Writeln('Введите номер: ');
readln(auto.Options[i].ID);
Writeln('Введите название опции: ');
readln(auto.Options[i].Name);

Setlength(Cars, length(cars)+1);
Cars[length(cars)-1] := auto;
end;
```

итерация идет по j, а массив вы разыменовываете почему-то по i.

**Update**

динамические массивы начинаются с нуля, а не с единицы, т.е. не `for i := 1 to length(cars) do`, а `for i := 0 to High(cars) do`

И еще ошибка: процедуру по добавлению авто надо объявить так: `Procedure AddAutos(var Cars: tCars);`  вот теперь она будет менять переданную переменную, в противном случае всё работает, но результат в глобальную переменную `cars` не передается.
Старайтесь отвыкать от одинаковых имен локальных и глобальных переменных - так будет проще в дальнейшем.

Comment: Да, заменил i на j в auto.Options и теперь ввод работает. Но с выводом проблемы: как только ввёл данные, он заново вывел меню и когда нажимаю 2 (Список авто), он опять запускает меню, хотя должен обращаться к процедуре TypeAutos, которая выводит всё, что только что было добавлено. Почему так происходит? Где ошибка?

Comment: динамические массивы начинаются с нуля, а не с единицы, т.е. не for i := 1 to length(cars) do, а for i := 0 to High(cars) do

Comment: Понял, но компилятор всё равно выводит меню

Comment: смотрите обновленный ответ

Comment: Да, теперь всё работает, но программа выдаёт ошибку: индекс находился вне границы массива после 2 номера опции. Т.е. выводит все данные, кроме последней опции и выводит ошибку

Comment: Я уж надеялся, что вы сами заметите: циклите по j, а именуете массив по i

Comment: Это я заметил и исправил. И он выдаёт первые две опции, а на третьей прерывается

Comment: у меня после всех введенных правок все работает, проверяйте всё же индексы: Writeln('Номер: ',Cars[i].Options[j].ID);
Writeln('Название опции: ',Cars[i].Options[j].Name);
end;

Comment: Теперь почти всё отлично, но он почему-то выводит данные по-очереди. Т.е. сначала все данные и опцию 1 (опцию 2 и опцию 3 выводит пустые строки), потом все данные и опцию 1 и 2 (опция 3 - пустая) и, наконец, все данные. Почему так?

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, помочь с данным вопросом: почему он не проходит внутренний цикл for для номера и названия опции весь сразу, а проходит его по очереди, выдавая первый результат в виде сначала первой опции, и нулями в двух остальных, потом, заходя во внешний цикл for для марки, модели..., двух первых опций и нулём в последней, и только потом всех трёх опций?

Comment: Хм... у вас, в итоге, такой текст программы? выложил сюда: https://pastebin.com/gpNMJCNL

Comment: Да, всё так, за исключением переменной auto, которую мой Pascal ABC почему-то не воспринимает как идентификатор. Все "auto" у меня заменены на просто "а"

Comment: Хм.. В Pascal ABC auto не зарезервировано? Но, не важно. Так вот, у меня этот код работает без видимых проблем и выводит всё корректно

Comment: Вот, что выводит Pascal ABC: https://ibb.co/jkK6LG
Каким компилятором Вы пользуетесь?

Comment: Всё, увидел. Процедуру добавления перепишите: https://pastebin.com/d2rVCqvJ

Comment: Точно! Теперь всё работает! Спасибо Вам большое! Не могли бы Вы пояснить, почему end нужно ставить сразу после цикла?

Comment: В противном случае вы каждый раз проводите операции с массивом, увеличивая его на и присваивая последнему члену текущее значение. Фактически, первые члены не заполняются.

Comment: Получается, что вместо одной записи в массиве он записывал три, в которые поочерёдно записывал все три опции. И выводил он тоже три разных записи массива, а не одну?

Comment: Он создавал три, но в первые две писал частично чушь.

Comment: Я так и понял. Спасибо большое, очень помогли!