# Процедура поиска в массиве

Tags: алгоритм, pascal, отладка, процедуры

Есть задача из предыдущего вопроса: [предыдущий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/753002/pascal-%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B)

Нужно организовать поиск по массиву. Вот мой код процедуры, которая вызывается из меню:

```
Procedure SearchAuto(Cars: tCars); //поиск в массиве
Var
i, j, k, num: integer;
name: string;
Begin
Writeln('Введите номер: ');
readln(num);
Writeln('Введите название опции: ');
readln(name);
for i := 0 to high(cars) do begin
for j := 1 to 3 do begin
if (num = Cars[i].Options[j].ID) and (name = Cars[i].Options[j].Name) then
Writeln('Марка: ',Cars[i].Mark);
Writeln('Модель: ',Cars[i].Model);
Writeln('Цвет: ',Cars[i].Colour);
Writeln('Цена: ',Cars[i].Price);
for k := 1 to 3 do begin
Writeln('Опция номер ',Cars[i].Options[k].ID, ':');
Writeln(Cars[i].Options[k].Name);
writeln();
end;
end;
end;
End;
```

В нём есть как минимум две ошибки.

Первая - условие if

> if (num = Cars[i].Options[j].ID) and (name = Cars[i].Options[j].Name) then

работает некорректно: оно выводит слова при их частичном совпадении. Т.е., скажем, при сравнении слов "Опция1" и "Опция123л" оно посчитает их равными и выведет в поиске. Нужно, чтобы условие if работало только при полном совпадении слова, за исключением регистра букв.

Вторая - вывод данных. Почему-то компилятор выводит параметры автомобиля три раза, причём первый раз с маркой, а остальные два - без неё. Нужно, чтобы он выводил параметры всех автомобилей, у которых опции совпали, только один раз.

Comment: `оно посчитает их равными и выведет в поиске` не совсем так. Марку не выведет. А модель и далее - да, выведет. Потому что только марка входит в условие if. Вам нужен составной оператор - begin-end в этом условии. Остальные проблемы - тоже по всей вероятности растут оттуда же

Comment: Где их конкретно нужно добавить?

Comment: используйте "лесенку" при написании кода

Comment: `Где их конкретно нужно добавить?` собственно, ответ вы уже получили. Но на всякий случай - добавлять begin-end нужно там, где вы хотите получить "если вот это условие действительно, то нужно, чтобы выполнилась вот эта **группа** операторов". И необходимую группу заключаете в begin-end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам повезло (или не повезло), что паскалевское `for` оставляет счетчик цикла равным последнему значению, а не на единицу больше.

```
var
  foundOption: boolean;

...
for i := low(cars) to high(cars) do 
begin
  foundOption := false;
  for j := 1 to 3 do 
  begin
    if (num = Cars[i].Options[j].ID) and (name = Cars[i].Options[j].Name) then
      foundOption := true;
  end;
  if foundOption then
  begin
    Writeln('Марка: ',Cars[i].Mark);
    Writeln('Модель: ',Cars[i].Model);
    Writeln('Цвет: ',Cars[i].Colour);
    Writeln('Цена: ',Cars[i].Price);
    for k := 1 to 3 do 
    begin
      Writeln('Опция номер ',Cars[i].Options[k].ID, ':');
      Writeln(Cars[i].Options[k].Name);
    end;
    Writeln();
  end;
end;
```

*Update*

> Что значит "не показали, что из себя представляет tCars"? И почему
>   хорошо, что паскалевское for оставляет счетчик цикла равным последнему
>   значению, а не на единицу больше?

Где-то у Вас объявлен тип `TCars`. Например, так:

```
type
  TCars = array of TCar;
```

или

```
type
  TCars = array[5..14] of TCar;
```

`Low` и `High` сработают для любого диапазона индексов в определении типа.

Стандартный цикл в С завершается с значением счетчика на единицу большим, чем индекс последнего элемента массива. Если бы так было и здесь, то Вы бы сразу увидели мусор, выведенный в консоль. Это, возможно, подтолкнуло бы Вас в нужном направлении в поиске ошибки.

*Update*

А, нашел определение `TCars` - динамический массив. В данном случае разницы нет, так как `Low` для динамического массива всегда возвращает ноль.

Comment: Почему нужно использовать low(cars) вместо 0? И почему хорошо, что паскалевское for оставляет счетчик цикла равным последнему значению, а не на единицу больше?

Comment: @A.Hall 1 - Потому что Вы не показали, что из себя представляет `tCars`. 2 - Потому что в С Вы бы вылезли за границу массива.

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, пояснить эти два момента в первом вопросе?

Comment: @A.Hall Наверное, могу. Сформулируйте, пожалуйста, что требует пояснения.

Comment: Что значит "не показали, что из себя представляет tCars"? И почему хорошо, что паскалевское for оставляет счетчик цикла равным последнему значению, а не на единицу больше?

Comment: И почему хорошо, "что паскалевское for оставляет счетчик цикла равным последнему значению, а не на единицу больше?" в данном случае? Кажется это лишняя информация к данному вопросу/ответу.

Comment: @Kromster дописал в ответе.

Comment: @Igor не пойму, на какую строку вы указываете, что она вывела бы мусор? Вроде бы в вопросе все итераторы и массивы совпадают (если Options 1..3)

Comment: Уточнение, стандартный цикл в С завершается с значением счетчика на единицу большим, чем верхняя граница цикла, а не индекс последнего элемента массива (цикл же не знает, по массиву его используют или как-то еще). <зануда_mode>

Comment: @Kromster Спасибо большое, очень помогли!

Comment: @Kromster да, Вы правы. `begin`ы в конце строк меня сбили.

Comment: Не подскажите, пожалуйста, как организовать сохранение данных из этого массива в файл и вывод данных массива из файла в консоль? Вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/754963/Сохранение-данных-из-массива-в-текстовый-файл-и-чтение-из-файла-в-окне-программы?noredirect=1#comment1165709_754963